# I get Undefined variable when I am using AWS configuration file with the service builder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to integrate this PHP framework https://github.com/panique/mini with Amazon S3:s configuration file with the service builder http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html#using-a-configuration-file-with-the-service-builder

Best would be if I could integrate it with the existing config.php https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/application/config/config.php but I don't know how I should do with this line.

```
$aws = Aws::factory('/path/to/custom/config.php');
```

Since I already include config.php in another part of the code

This is what I have tried but don't know why it does not work

Created a new file aws-config.php in the folder config and included it in my project. aws-config.php have the following code (with my correct keys).

```
return array(
    // Bootstrap the configuration file with AWS specific features
    'includes' => array('_aws'),
    'services' => array(
        // All AWS clients extend from 'default_settings'. Here we are
        // overriding 'default_settings' with our default credentials and
        // providing a default region setting.
        'default_settings' => array(
            'params' => array(
                array(
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
                    )
                ),
                'region' => 'us-west-1'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I want to access my credentials in my controller that looks like this: https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/application/controller/songs.php

I've implemented it like this from the documentation

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Aws;

// Create the AWS service builder, providing the path to the config file
$aws = Aws::factory(APP . 'config/aws-config.php');
$client = $aws->get('s3');

class Album extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
            foreach ($images as &$image) {
                $image->imageThumbnailUrl = $client->getObjectUrl($resizedBucket, 'resized-'.$image->image_name, '+10 minutes');

            }
...
...
```

I get the error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: client in Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function getObjectUrl() on a non-object in

I use $client and getObjectUrl in my loop.

My code works fine if I use "Passing credentials into a client factory method" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html#passing-credentials-into-a-client-factory-method in the index method in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has nothing to do with the AWS SDK or the panique/mini framework. You cannot declare variables outside of a class definition and expect to be able to use them inside the class definition. That is just how variable scoping works in PHP. You need to pass the s3Client object into the Controller somehow, or instantiate it inside of the controller.

You can literally move these lines into your index method, and it should work.

```
// Create the AWS service builder, providing the path to the config file
$aws = Aws::factory(APP . 'config/aws-config.php');
$client = $aws->get('s3');
```